# All-day events not showing in scheduler in day views

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm trying to show organizational events, such as holidays, on the calendar in addition to scheduled events such as meetings. I'm showing five scheduler / calendar view options: timelineWeek,agendaDay,agendaTwoDay,agendaWeek,month

In 'agendaWeek' and 'month' views, these all-day events show, both when resource ID is not specified and when the event is tied to all resources IDs through an array:

[image]

However, on the 'timelineWeek', 'agendaDay', and 'agendaTwoDay' views, these "allDay" events will not show. The events are injected through AJAX which returns:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1000001",
    "resourceIds": "['16121','14174','14175','14842','14843','14844']",
    "start": "2017-01-27T00:00Z",
    "end": "2017-01-27T00:00Z",
    "allDay": true,
    "title": "ResourceIDs Array Day",
    "eventStatus": null,
    "borderColor": "#FF0000",
    "backgroundColor": "#F9626B"
  },
  {
    "id": "1000001",
    "start": "2017-01-27T00:00Z",
    "end": "2017-01-28T00:00Z",
    "allDay": true,
    "title": "ResourceID Null Day",
    "eventStatus": null,
    "borderColor": "#FF0000",
    "backgroundColor": "#F9626B"
  }
]
```

Is it possible to show all-day events on the scheduler?

Comment: Hi! Can you post your code?

Comment: try setting all-day to true for each view (each view can have different options) https://fullcalendar.io/docs/agenda/allDaySlot/

Answer (score 0):

Like most of my problems, this issue was caused by my own mistake. The list of resource IDs in the JSON was malformed (a string, not an array).

Bad, fails:

`"resourceIds": "['16121','14174','14175','14842','14843','14844']",`

Better, works:

`"resourceIds": ['16121','14174','14175','14842','14843','14844'],`